# Project Euler #2, Fibonacci, javascript attemp

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I was attempting to do some problems on project euler.  For the second one I did get the correct answer but I cheated a bit.

**Heres the problem:**

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

**Heres my code:**

```
var fib = [1,2];
var i = 0;
var sum = 0;
while (fib[0] + fib[1] < 4000000){
    i = fib[0] + fib[1];
    console.log(i); //just to show myself the number came out correctly.
    fib[0] = fib[1];
    fib[1] = i;

    if (i % 2 === 0){
        sum += i;
    }
}
console.log(sum + 2);
```

I added sum by 2 because I can't figure a way for the code to add the initial fib[1], which is a even number itself.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to add to the sum 3 instead of 2. Because you are not adding to sum the first two numbers of the fibonacci sequence 1 and 2

Comment: Well, the sequence really starts with `[1, 1]` or `[0, 1]`, right? If you used that as your starting point it would work without the "cheat". If you are going to start with `[1, 2]`, then you need to initialize `sum` to 2 since you will be skipping over that number

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution

```
var sum = 0;
var term1 = 1;
var term2 = 1;

while (term2 < 4000000) {
    term2 = term1 + term2;
    term1 = term2 - term1;
    sum += term2 % 2 === 0 ? term2 : 0;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start with [1, 2], the first fibonacci number that you get is 3.

In your loop you have:

```
i = 1+2 = 3
i = 2+3 = 5
```

So simply start with [0, 1]:

```
i = 0+1 = 1
i = 1+1 = 2
i = 1+2 = 3
```

Fixed code:

```
var fib = [0,1];
var i = 0;
var sum = 0;
while (fib[0]+fib[1] < 4000000){
    i= fib[0]+fib[1];
    fib[0]=fib[1];
    fib[1]=i;

        if(i%2 === 0){
        sum += i;
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var sum = 0, i = 0, j = 0, k = 1; 4e6 > j + k; i++) i = j + k, j = k, k = i, sum += 0 == i % 2 ? i : 0;
```

> It could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
let num1 = 0; 
let num2 = 1;
let total = 0;
let num3 = 0;
let i = 0;
while(num1 + num2 < 4000000){
     num3 = num1 + num2;
     num1 = num2; //as loop keep going is changes the position of number
     num2 = num3; //as loop keep going is changes the position of number
     if(num3 % 2 === 0 ){ // check weather number is even or not 
        total += num3;    //every even number gets added
        }
     i++
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: A block of code alone is not enough of an answer, even more when your code has no comments. Try to add a few explanation on important points where you made change from poster's code, explain how your implementation solve the problem from the poster.

Comment: Thank for telling me my mistake. Actually i have just started programming i don't have good idea about adding comment but i tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
function firstNofFibonacci(n)
{
    let fibArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (fibArr.length > 1) {
            fibArr.push(fibArr[fibArr.length - 1] + 
                fibArr[fibArr.length - 2]);
        } else {
            fibArr.push(i);
        };
    };
    return fibArr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my code for the same problem. It is not perfect but I hope this will help someone who reads this.

```js
function fibonacci(stop) {
  var a = 1, b = 0, c, storage = []
  for (var i = 0; a < stop; i++) {
    c = a
    a = a + b
    b = c
    if (b%2 == 0) {
      let even = b
      storage.unshift(even)
    }
  }
  var all = storage.reduce((x, y) => {return x + y}, 0)
  console.log(all)
}

fibonacci(4000000); // 4613732
```

well, what I did here is that I create a function with the stop parameter (where you tell the function to stop) and then I create variables to make the Fibonacci sequence and create a variable where I can store the even values. Then push all the even values in the array, at the end of the function I add all the values in a variable and console.log() the value

If you have suggestions or comments all ears :)

Comment: If some thing is not perfect don't write it as answers. As you say it is not perfect then it is low quality answer and it should not be in answer section.